# change sftp to ftp

Tags: ssh, centos, ftp

I recently installed a CentOS machine for a couple of game servers.
I followed some tutorials on the web for that.
But. I want to `sftp` to store data on the server but it is very slow, I read that `ftp` is much faster. So my question is:
Can I change my SFTP to a FTP server and if so, how.

Comment: SFTP isn't likely to be much faster than FTP. If you read that somewhere, don't trust this source. You can't “change” your SFTP server to an FTP server, they're completely different. You can run an FTP server in parallel with the SFTP (SSH really) server, but the question is why you'd want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to analyze why SFTP is "slow".

Does the CPU-usage on the server or client raise to a very high level during transfer?

Are there any lost packets on the network layer?

Do your duplex settings on the network adapters match those of the network devices (switches, routers, whatever) match each other?

Apart from that FTP uses a very different protocol, with no encryption and that can be difficult to get through firewalls, while SFTP operates over SSH and generally Just Works.

Comment: @EliHeady Gilles was so kind to correct this. Today is not my day...